# Querying table for multiple combinations and default values

Tags: database, oracle, lookup

I have a table like

```
City    POSTAGE   PRICE**                   

HOUSTON   DEFAULT    20
DEFAULT   AIR        14
DEFAULT   GROUND     30
DEFAULT   DEFAULT    40
```

Now i want to query for price on this table with a combination like 'CHICAGO,GROUND'
which should check if the perfect combination exists, else i should substitute DEFAULT and search for the value..

example,
HOUSTON,AIR should return 14
HOUSTON,GROUND should return 20
HOUSTON,FEDEX should return 20
CHICAGO,FEDEX should return 40

Is there a way to achieve this instead of writing multiple queries ..

thank you!

Comment: By what reasoning should HOUSTON,GROUND return 20 (HOUSTON,DEFAULT) rather than 30 (DEFAULT,GROUND)?  Is that because CITY has priority over POSTAGE?  Or perhaps always return the minimum PRICE?

Comment: Yes , CITY has priority over postage  (because there's an entry in the table, default is for which, there's no entry)

Comment: But if you're searching for HOUSTON,GROUND, there's *both* a HOUSTON,DEFAULT, and a DEFAULT,GROUND.  So, why is HOUSTON,DEFAULT a better match than DEFAULT,GROUND?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the SQL*Plus syntax for passing parameters, you may need to change that to suit:

```
 select price
 from your_table
 where ( city = '&p_city' or city = 'DEFAULT') 
 and ( postage = '&p_postage' or postage = 'DEFAULT') 
 order by case when city = '&p_city' then 1 else 2 end 
          , case when postage = '&p_postage'  then 1 else 2 end
```

This will return multiple rows but presumably you want only the one PRICE.  The ORDER BY clause prioritises matches on CITY over matches on POSTAGE.  You can then select the first row.

Comment: Thanks much!, I have another column called 'packagetype'. When I try to add another case in order by, this is matching 'DEFAULT' and DEFAULT' for first two fields.

Comment: And the teaching is: if you don't provide all the details in your question you will get an incomplete answer.  So your choices are - edit your question to include all the information or figure it out yourself.